# .htaccess rule skipping $2 not matched uri segment from the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want below request and response

- 1 
  Request: https://example.com/de/  
  Expected: https://example.com/de
- 2 
  Request: https://example.com/de/fr/path 
  Expected: https://example.com/de/path
- 3 #default english 
  https://example.com/def/frq/path  
  https://example.com/en

```
RewriteEngine On

#Check for files that do not contain the language string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en [R=301,L]

#Capture the language string and present it as the variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]{2})/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Tried with some changes in %2 segment uri but no help so far, anyone did this earlier?
Let me know if more description required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Keep these Rules at the top of your .htaccess Rules file. I am assuming that you have rules present to serve your newly rewritten urls in your htaccess rules file.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##1st kind of urls, to remove / from end of it.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/?$ $1 [R=301,L]

##Handle https://example.com/de/fr/en/de/en TO https://example.com/de urls.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}/)*(?:[a-zA-Z]{2})/?$ $1 [R=301,L]

##Handle https://example.com/de/fr/path TO https://example.com/de/path urls.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}/)*(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

##handle https://example.com/def/frq/path TO https://example.com/en urls here.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{3,})/.*$ en [R=301,L]
```

[Online demo for 3rd rule regex](https://regex101.com/r/1kEzKy/1/)

[Online demo for 2nd rule regex](https://regex101.com/r/H7gF8H/1/)

---

---

***EDIT:*** Or to check rules to start with a 2 letter specific language try following then, I have used en,us,de,fr languages, you can add more to it as per your need too.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##1st kind of urls, to remove / from end of it.
RewriteRule ^(en|us|de|fr)/?$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]

##Handle https://example.com/de/fr/en/de/en TO https://example.com/de urls.
RewriteRule ^(en|us|de|fr)/(?:(?:en|us|de|fr)/)*(?:en|us|de|fr)/?$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]

##Handle https://example.com/de/fr/path TO https://example.com/de/path urls.
RewriteRule ^(en|us|de|fr)/(?:(?:en|us|de|fr)/)*(.*)/?$ $1/$2 [NC,R=301,L]

##handle https://example.com/def/frq/path TO https://example.com/en urls here.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{3,})/.*$ en [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it gives http://example.com/de/fr for http://example.com/de/fr/path 
need path and rest language uri must be removed

Comment: @AmmyTech, Sure I have changed it now, could you please do test it once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: It worked for example.com/de/fr/path 
but not for below one, need generic one
http://example.com/de/fr/en/de/path/

Comment: @AmmyTech, ok so url `thebrain.space/de/fr/en/de/path` should become?

Comment: example.com/de/fr/en/de/path should become example.com/de/path

Comment: @AmmyTech, ok sure, I have edited my Rules now, kindly do check them once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: example.com/en/fr/en/de/path should become example.com/en/path

Comment: @AmmyTech, sure, its generic Rule now. I have tested its regex online too, kindly do check it once.

Comment: Great that worked but if this comes http://example.com/de/fr/en/de/en then I want http://example.com/de/
or
http://example.com/en/fr/en/de/fr then
http://example.com/en

Comment: hope u understood now

Comment: so only first language in the uri and path other than language uri need in expected url

Comment: @AmmyTech, sure, I got it, I have added 4th Rule at last of my htaccess Rules file now, please do check it and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: for http://example.com/en/fr/en/de/fr it gives http://example.com/en/fr

Comment: @AmmyTech, Sorry there was a typo, fixed it now, please check updated rules file, last rule is updated now. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233922/discussion-between-ammytech-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @AmmyTech, could you please comments here, sorry can't join chat room.

Comment: getting same as before

Comment: @AmmyTech, oh ok, I have changed order of their processing, kindly do check it now. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: it gives http://example.com/fr/hagshghasgagh/en for  http://example.com/fr/fr/en/en/fr/fr/fr/hagshghasgagh/en
can we have 404 or http://example.com/fr

Comment: also If want to allow only specific language like en,fr,es only? then how will be the regex

Comment: @AmmyTech, `it gives example.com/fr/hagshghasgagh/en for example.com/fr/fr/en/en/fr/fr/fr/hagshghasgagh/en can we have 404 or example.com/fr` could ou please explain more on this please.

Comment: I mean only mention language can be allowed like en, es and fr

Comment: @AmmyTech, Ok, please do check my EDIT rules then, with language specific code.